# Webpack - String replacement in SASS/SCSS '@import' statements

Tags: webpack, sass

Currently refining a shared webpack build for 4 identical sites where the styling only differs by site-specific variable overrides in SASS and am looking for a way to dynamically replace `@import` references at the top of the SASS files prior to the `sass-loader` or `css-loader` running and SASS compiler running.

For example, a component like `text-input.scss` may have the following structure:

```
@import '../../styles/global/_variables.scss';
@import '../../styles/<<<SITENAME>>>/_variables.scss';

.some-class {
    ...
}
```

I'd like a way to replace the string `<<<SITENAME>>>` with an `env.sitename` variable passed in at build-time, prior to SASS/SCSS compiler kicking in.

example:

```
webpack env.sitename=site1 --progress --config ./wp.config.js
```

The result would be that by the time the `sass-loader` was run, string-replaced files would look to the SASS compiler like:

```
@import '../../styles/global/_variables.scss';
@import '../../styles/site1/_variables.scss';

.some-class {
    ...
}
```

I tried `string-replace-loader` but was unable to get it to run and perform replacements prior to the SASS compiler attempting to resolve all of the filenames, which makes sense given how webpack's module resolution works.

Is there a plugin or loader that can solve this problem from within webpack?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually figured out the "webpack way" of handling this issue - **create an alias**.

Using the example above the command from above:

```
webpack env.sitename=site1 --progress --config ./wp.config.js
```

I created an alias called `siteStyles` in my webpack config:

```
{
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...
      siteStyles: path.join(ROOT_DIR, `path/to/${env.sitename}/scss`)
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

** Note: `ROOT_DIR` is a variable representing the root of the project*

Having the alias handy we can now take advantage of a path resolution feature of SCSS/SASS using the tilde (`~`) in our SCSS/SASS files like so:

`@import ~siteStyles/component/foo;`

and the import will resolve to `foo.scss` in the `ROOT_DIR/path/to/site1/scss/component` directory.

With the combination of webpack aliases, the `~` feature of SASS/SCSS, and absolute filesystem paths I was able to resolve the proper site-specific styles during build.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and i fix it using `string-replace-loader` what you have to do is use it int he scss rule before the others loader (putting as the last of element of `use` array)
for example :

```
{
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                        options: {
                            strict: true,
                            multiple: [
                                {
                                    search: '<<<SITENAME>>>',
                                    replace: env.sitename
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
```

this snipett is taken from my code in which i have to replace multiple strings, but you can adjust it as you want.